# Aggregate values by parents recursively in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, aggregate, recursive-query

Consider the the following example structure:

#### DEPARTMENT

- ID
- PARENT_ID
- NAME
- DEPTH

#### PROJECT

- ID
- NAME
- COST
- DEPARTMENT_ID

Some data, just for the sake of the examples bellow:

```
| ID | PARENT_ID | NAME  | DEPTH |
|----|-----------|-------|-------|
|  1 |      NULL | DEPT1 |     1 |
|  2 |         1 | DEPT2 |     2 |
|  3 |         1 | DEPT3 |     2 |
|  4 |         2 | DEPT4 |     3 |
|  5 |         3 | DEPT5 |     3 |
|  6 |      NULL | DEPT6 |     1 |
|  7 |         6 | DEPT7 |     2 |


|  ID  |  NAME  | COST  | DEPARTMENT_ID |
|------|--------|-------|---------------|
|   1  |  PRJ1  |  100  |      1        |
|   2  |  PRJ2  |  200  |      2        |
|   3  |  PRJ3  |  300  |      3        |
|   4  |  PRJ4  |  400  |      4        |
|   5  |  PRJ5  |  500  |      5        |
|   6  |  PRJ6  |  600  |      6        |
|   7  |  PRJ7  |  700  |      7        |
```

Now, I need to somehow aggregate the costs of the, projects by one department and then by its direct children.

If the choosen filter is **DEPT1**, the intented result is:

```
| LINE | DEPARTMENT_ID  | PARENT_ID |  NAME  | AGGREGATE_COST |
|------|----------------|-----------|--------|----------------|
|  1   |       1        |   NULL    |  DEPT1 |           1500 |
|  2   |       2        |     1     |  DEPT2 |            600 |
|  3   |       3        |     1     |  DEPT3 |            800 |
```

Where:

- Line 3 aggregate is PRJ5 (of DEPT5, which is child of DEPT3) + PRJ3 (of DEPT3) cost
- Line 2 aggregate is PRJ4 (of DEPT4, which is child of DEPT2) + PRJ2 (of DEPT2) cost
- Line 1 aggregate is the sum of his childrens aggregates.
- PRJ6 and PRJ7 costs are ignored because the are from DEPT6 and DEPT7, and those are not in the hierachy of DEPT1 (DEPT6 would be his sibling, not child)

EDIT:

```
|  ID  |  NAME  | COST  | DEPARTMENT_ID |
|------|--------|-------|---------------|
|   1  |  PRJ1  |   1   |      1        |
|   2  |  PRJ2  |   1   |      1        |
|   3  |  PRJ3  |   1   |      2        |
|   4  |  PRJ4  |   1   |      2        |
|   5  |  PRJ5  |   1   |      4        |
```

In this scenario, the solution ivanzg presented, doesn't seem to work.
I get doubled results for the projects in the highers ranks

If I get the aggregate for DEPT1, it returns something similar to this:

```
| LINE | DEPARTMENT_ID  | PARENT_ID |  NAME  | AGGREGATE_COST |
|------|----------------|-----------|--------|----------------|
|  1   |       1        |   NULL    |  DEPT1 |              8 |
|  2   |       2        |   NULL    |  DEPT1 |              4 |
```

Answer (score 3):

You can tag rows in a hierarchy query (to later create groups) by using CONNECT_BY_ROOT hierarchy operator. In the hierarchy query, by making all rows root rows you create every hierarchy combination, later only specified combinations are taken and aggregated. For your test data this returns what you specified.

```
SELECT ROOT_DEPT AS DEPARTMENT_ID
      ,ROOT_PARENT AS PARENT_ID
      ,ROOT_NAME AS NAME
      ,SUM(COST) AS AGGREGATE_COST
FROM (SELECT COST 
            ,CONNECT_BY_ROOT DEPARTMENT_ID ROOT_DEPT 
            ,CONNECT_BY_ROOT PARENT_ID ROOT_PARENT 
            ,CONNECT_BY_ROOT NAME ROOT_NAME
      FROM (SELECT   B.DEPARTMENT_ID
                    ,NVL(A.PARENT_ID,'0') PARENT_ID
                    ,A.NAME
                    ,SUM(B.COST) COST
            FROM  DEPARTMENT A 
                JOIN PROJECT B
                    ON A.ID = B.DEPARTMENT_ID
            --> GROUP COST OF PROJECTS IN THE SAME DEPARTMENT IF THERE ARE ANY
            GROUP BY B.DEPARTMENT_ID
                    ,NVL(A.PARENT_ID,'0')
                    ,A.NAME
            )
        --> MAKE ALL ROWS ROOT ROWS
      CONNECT BY PRIOR DEPARTMENT_ID = PARENT_ID
    )
WHERE ROOT_DEPT = 1 OR ROOT_PARENT  = 1
GROUP BY  ROOT_DEPT
         ,ROOT_PARENT
         ,ROOT_NAME
```

Comment: I was testing some stuff and eventually got a solution similar to this one (also by using CONNECT_BY_ROOT) but your code is way cleaner than mine :)

Comment: I've made a little mistake on my original explanation:

Line 1 (the one who is the main filter) should not aggregate the sum of his childrens aggregates, it should only show his own projects (kinda strange, but whatever the client wants, right? haha)

Anyway, I've just adapted your solution by removing the "ROOT_DEPT = 1 OR" in the where clause and adding a UNION ALL in the end, selecting the projects from the main department.

Comment: ivanzg: I've encountered what seems to be a bug . I've edited the original post